# See if there is a form inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a div with an id like: `comment-box-5` and I want to see using javascript if there is a form inside of it if so remove it if not add it (so it toggles when I call the function). I wrote this piece of code to try to do this:

```
function reply(id){
    console.log(document.getElementById('comment-id-' + id).innerHTML.indexOf(document.getElementById('form-' + id)));
    if (document.getElementById('comment-id-' + id).innerHTML.indexOf(document.getElementById('form-' + id))) {
        var form = replyFn(id);
        document.getElementById('comment-id-' + id).appendChild(form);
    } else {
        //for toogle effect
        document.getElementById('comment-id-' + id).removeChild(document.getElementById("form-" + id));
    }
}
```

And I tried executing it but `console.log(document.getElementById('comment-id-' + id).innerHTML.indexOf(document.getElementById('form-' + id)));` prints -1 even if there is a form inside.

What am I doing wrong? how can I actually see if there is a form in the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your condition to :

```
if ( document.querySelector('#comment-id-' + id +'>#form-' + id) ) {
    //Your if logic
}else{
    //Your else logic
}
```

**Snippet :**

```js
var id = 1;

if (document.querySelector('#comment-id-' + id + '>#form-' + id)) {
  console.log('Remove form');
} else {
  console.log('Add form');
}
```

```html
<div id="comment-id-1">
  <form id="form-1"></form>
</div>
```

Comment: would this be better than the other answer. They both work for me but is one of them subjectivly better (like faster or saver?)

Comment: @igor what do you mean, I mean taking in consideration your earlier comment

Comment: yeah but i mean between the code in your comment and the other answer

Comment: @Igor it's fixed now, (thanks for your comment), the selector should go faster since it wil make just one operation when the other suggestion will select two elements then compare them.. what mean 3 operations..

Answer (score 1):

Try using contains on the div without `innerHTML` like below, I changed the code from yours a bit to do the example but it should work for yours as well.

```js
 console.log(document.getElementById('comment-id-1').contains(document.getElementById('form-id-1')));
```

```html
<div id="comment-id-1"><form id="form-id-1"></form></div>
```